# looking for local methods

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am looking for something which is best described as local method. The aim is to run certain a block in a method (and only in this method), which has access to local variables, e.g. as shortest (not working!) example something like:

```
void localMethodTest(int number, boolean whileLoop){
    double otherNumber = 4;

    block: {
      otherNumber+=number;
      System.out.println(otherNumber);
    }

    if(whileLoop){
        while(otherNumber<42){
            block;
        }
    }
    else{
        otherNumber=8;
        block;
    }
}
```

My only solution so far is to make the whole method as an inner Class with the local variables as fields and the block as a method of this class, but this is a little bit overhead and looks terrible.
Is there another way to solve this despite of copy-pasting the block everywhere, since there might be changes to it several times in the future?

Comment: read about closures in java 8

Comment: Just make another method that takes number and othernumber as a parameter. Why do you need a class?

Comment: What is your use case? it looks like the X-y problem

Comment: @Ferrybig I am using this to extract a List depending on several variables, mostly Date, but also a control list. Right now I have two different methods, which share a large chunk of code, but mostly differs in the way they iterate over the list and now I want to merge them.

Comment: @DwB Lambda expressions won't work since they behave like local classes (which means my variables have to be effectively final).

Comment: The not really good looking solution (as cricket suggested): I encapsulated the block in a method with tons of parameters (thanks refactor), but I am still wondering why there is no code-mirroring in java or at least in the IDE.